# Returning to a previous instance of DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am coding an app with **dialogs**. I read that it is not advisable to nest **dialogs**, so I set up an **interface** to return the values selected (with **NumberPickers**) in an **AlertDialog** back to the activity that called the **DialogFragment** in the first place.

This **activity** then calls another **DialogFragment** whose **dialog** gives the user a chance to confirm what he chose in the first **dialog**. If he confirms, then an **intent** takes him to the next **activity**, but if not, I want him to be able to return to the previous **instance** of the first **dialog** and make the necessary changes.

I tried deleting the command `dialog.dismiss()` from the code that is implemented by the **positive button** on the first **dialog**, but to no avail, when I left the second **dialog** the first **dialog** was gone.

I then tried to "pop" the **backstack** with **FragmentManager**, in the hope that the previous **instance** of the **dialog** would reappear. I was wrong.

```
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.reset_duration, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
               //return to the previous instance of SDDialogFragment 
                int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                if (count != 0) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
```

I think my error lies in two points:

a) I don't have a realistic understanding of how **dialogs** can remain active.

b) I am confusing instances of **fragments** with instances of **dialogs**.

Would someone please advise me if it is at all feasible to do what I want to do, or, should I just think in terms of transferring the values by using **Bundle** and forget about returning to a previous **instance** ? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The dialog cannot remain active but You can get Your dialog back in onDismiss().

try this:
make Your Activity implement onDismissListener
before showing Your dialog set a dismiss listener `yourDialog.setOnDismissListener(this);`

Then You will get Your dialog back in onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)

Comment: How to I get to show the dialog again? (there is no option to write dialog.show() in onDismiss()  )

Comment: You can keep everything the user selected in Your dialog as class members and get it in onDismiss. Then, when You need to show that dialog again, You pass this data to the new dialog You are creating and repopulate the fields in onCreate of the dialog itself.

Comment: I tried using getDialog() in onDismiss() to extract the data of the class members but I get a NullPointerException. What do you think?:)

Comment: My code that gets the NPE is: ' NumberPicker np1 = (NumberPicker)getDialog().findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);'

Comment: You already have it in onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) Your dialog is Dialoginterface dialog that you get. Just cast it to YourDialog

Comment: I have used ((Dialog) dialog).show in the onDismiss() in my first DialogFragment, but all this does is to show the dismissed dialog as soon as I have pressed a button in the AlertDialog, without implementing any of the code  written for that button press. I tried to use a boolean flag set by the button pressed in the second Dialog to control the above command and to get the dismissed first Dialog to show, but of course this doesn't trigger the onDismiss() of the first Dialog. Any ideas?